# TypeScript - Angular2 how to hide infoWindow when other gets opened?

Tags: angular

My code is in the HTML file:

```
<sebm-google-map-marker 
          *ngFor="let m of allMarkers; let i = index"
          [latitude]="m.gpsLongitude"
          [longitude]="m.gpsLatitude"
          [label]="m.label"
          (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.deviceId, i,infowindow)">
 in component.ts file 
 clickedMarker(deviceId: number, index: number,infowindow) {
    if(this.infowindow.Isopen){
     ..... ?
    }
       console.log(`clicked the marker: ${deviceId || index}`)
  }
```

What should be the code to track if last window is open then closed ?

I am not able track the if the last window is still open. I do not want to include jQuery for this.

Comment: Please let me the answer..if any